# English/German translation of Latin scientific texts in general, "Principia Generalia Theoriae Figurae Fluidorum in Statu Aequilibrii" in particular

Tags: soft-question, specific-reference, surface-tension, fluid-statics

I am trying to get my hands on an English or German translation of the seminal work by Gauss on  fluid shapes in equilibrium: "Principia generalia Theoriae Figurae Fluidorum in statu Aequilibrii [General principles of the theory of fluid shapes in a state of equilibrium]" from 1830.

I have found a [Latin version at hathitrust](http://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=nyp.33433069098576;view=1up;seq=9), but my Latin is virtually non-existent so that won't help me much.

Does someone know where I can find a German (Gauss was German after all) or English translation of this text? Or more in general, where I can find translations of scientific papers that where originally in Latin?

I have tried [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/), which seemed like a good place to start, but the specific paper I'm looking for is not there. Are there any other websites/projects that have similar databases that I might try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The German-language Wikipedia's page on [C.F. Gauß](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gau%C3%9F#.C3.9Cbersetzungen) lists a German translation of this work by Rudolf H. Weber, titled *Allgemeine Grundlagen einer Theorie der Gestalt von Flüssigkeiten im Zustand des Gleichgewichts* (publication date: 1903), available on the Internet Archive ([abstract](http://archive.org/details/allgemeinegrund00gausgoog), [pdf](http://archive.org/stream/allgemeinegrund00gausgoog#page/n4/mode/2up)).